# Why is my data missing from my file after transfering it over a socket?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ftp

I have the same code written for both server and client when attempting to upload a file to the server or download it from the server.

Downloading from the server works just fine and no data is missing in my file, but for some reason when uploading the file, not all is transmitted.

For instance, the file size on my client is smaller then when it is on the server. Then when it is opened up on the server, not all of it is there (since not all of it was received)

Server:

Algorithm:

- Get message from client
- Client tells server it wants to send a file (push)

Server reads where to put the file, and then receives the file from the client

```
  public static void GetClientMessage() {

            while (true) {
                try {

                    try {

                        try {
                            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("GetClientMessage():serverSocket:IOException:ex " + ex);
                            SendBackException(ex.toString());  // Inform client
                        }
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Waiting for client");
                            socket = serverSocket.accept();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.out.println("GetClientMessage():socket = serverSocket.accept():IOException:ex " + ex);
                            SendBackException(ex.toString());  // Inform client
                        }

                        bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                        brffReadIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                        // 1 - Read Line (it is the flag)
                        flag = brffReadIn.readLine();
                        // 2 - Handle Flag
                        HandleClientMessage(flag);

                        // Make decisions based upon that message
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("GetClientMessage():IOException:ex: " + ex);
                        SendBackException(ex.toString());  // Inform client
                    }

                    socket.close();
                    serverSocket.close();

                } // Close while loop
                catch (IOException ex) {
                    System.out.println("GetClientMessage:serverSocket.close():IOException:ex " + ex);
                }

            }

        }

           public static void HandleClientMessage(String message) {
           System.out.println("HandleClientMessage:message: '" + message + "'");
            switch (message) {
                case "push":
                    GetClientFile();
                    break;
                case "open_cla":
                    OpenCla();
                    break;
                case "kill_cla":
                    KillCla();
                    break;
                case "get":                
                    SendFile();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Gets path to where to place file on local
        public static String GetPath() {

            String filePath = " ";

            try {

                bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
                brffReadIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

                filePath = brffReadIn.readLine();

                System.out.println("Path to place file on local: " + filePath);

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(("GetPath():IOException:ex: " + ex));
            }
            return filePath;
        }

        public static void GetClientFile() {

            // Get the location where to place the file on local
            fileOnLocal = GetPath();

            int count;
            try {

                File file = new File(fileOnLocal);
                // Get the size of the file
                long length = file.length();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[16* 1024];
                InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileOnLocal);

                while ((count = in.read(bytes)) > 0) {
                    System.out.println("strByteArray: " + strByteArray);
                    out.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
                out.flush();

                System.out.println("File Size in bytes: " + file.length());
                if (file.length() < 5) {
                    System.out.println("FileClient:Error:File:" + fileOnLocal + " not found on server");
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    socket.close();
                    file.delete();
                    System.out.println("File:" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " deleted");
                } else {
                    out.close();
                    in.close();
                    socket.close();
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(":FileClient:GetServerFile():IOException:ex:" + ex);
            }
        }
```

Client Code:

Client tells the server it wants to "push" a file, then it passes the location where to put it on the server, then transmits the file

```
public void SendFlagToServer(String flag){

        try {

            bufOut = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            brffReadIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

            bufOut.write(flag);
            bufOut.newLine();
            bufOut.flush();

            System.out.println(host + ":SendFlagToServer: " + flag);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.Log((host + ":FileClient:SendFileToGetToServer():IOException:ex: " + ex));
        }
    }
```

After performing this the bytes are received on the client, but not all of them. Is there something I have coded wrong? Should my byte[] array be a different size? This will be used on Win7 & Win8, and possibly Mac in the future.

Edit: I figured it out. I was trying to send a message followed by a string of bytes too quickly.

This fixed my problem:

```
SendFlagToServer(fileLocaitonOnServer);
Thread.sleep(1000);
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing sockets after first client conneciton

```
socket.close();
serverSocket.close();
```

Solution:

> - Once you accept a client socket, create a new Thread with the socket connection and handle all IO operations in that thread
> - Do not close serverSocket. Once you close serverSocket, no more client socket connections will be accepted.

Can you provide the exception you are getting?

Comment: Even after making your changes the same issue is seen. I do not get any eceptions, the file size on my client is 7.69kb, and after transfer to the server it is, 6.32kb.

Comment: I figured it out...I was trying to send the file too quickly, so put a 1 second delay. I will update my question with the answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think this delay helping to re-create serverSocket since you are closing it. Never close serverSocket in your application and try with out delay